# Restoring VMware virtual machines created in ESXi to VMWare Player

Tags: vmware-esxi

Anyone have experience restoring VM files from a VM running on a proper server with ESXi to a windows/linux workstation host and running them with VMware Player?

I know you could do this as per the VMware vCenter Converter documentation, my question is does it work in reality?

I would use it as a poor mans "failover" scheme in case of server outage.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of functionality in ESXi that can't be offered by VMWare Player or even Workstation (e.g. more advanced virtual networking schemes,  storage pools etc.). If you use any of these, you are going to run into trouble quite fast, but if you stick to the very basic functionality, it can work.

This leaves the question of how you will get an up-to-date copy of a VM out of the ESXi host if it is down.

Comment: thanks. would get the data either from a backup image or from the disk in the server that went down - that would be a process but is doable.